# How do I : find a string in a bunch of files, if found then copy the file over

Tags: linux, file, find

I have to restore a mail archive; thousands of .eml files.

I'd like to run a single 'find' command that will:

1. Look for a particular string
2. If found, copy the file over to a separate folder.

Any quick help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a recursive `grep` along with [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
grep "the string I want to find" -r --include=\*.eml -l -Z ROOTDIR | xargs -0 cp -t TARGETDIR
```

This will search all `.eml` files under the `ROOTDIR` directory for the desired string and move them to the directory `TARGETDIR`.  The `-Z` in `grep` and the `-0` in `xargs` ensure that even filenames with wacky characters will still work properly.

**Edit:** Changed the `mv` to a `cp`

Answer (score 1):

I like Adam's answer, but if you want to use `find`, you can do something like

```
find DIR -name '*.eml' -exec sh process.sh {} \;
```

where `process.sh` can look like

```bash
SEARCH='Doe'
DEST='..'
s=$(grep "$SEARCH" "$1")
if [ "$s" != '' ] ; then
    cp "$1" "$DEST"
fi
```

Comment: Nice too; but admit adam's one is more elegant :) Thank you very much !

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is that you fork off anywhere from 2*N to 3*N separate processes, where N is the number of `.eml` files.  If there are a lot of small files, the overhead of starting and stopping a large number of processes will be non-trivial.  If, however, there are a small number of large files, then the overhead will be negligible.